# Search and replace a keyword in the response content using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, search, replace

I need to rewrite a keyword (the old domainname) in 100,000 files and I can't search and replace it in the database.
maybe there is a solution with htaccess?

old: 
the yellow dog clicks always www.domainname1.tld

new: 
the yellow dog clicks always www.domainname2.tld

in PHP:

```
$bodytag = "the yellow dog clicks always www.domainname1.tld";

$bodytag = str_replace("domainname1.tld", "domainname2.tld", $bodytag);
```

Comment: You need to edit HTML files? Or you want Apache to alter the content on the fly? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way to do this within htaccess. There are Apache modules that are designed to manipulate content. For example, mod_substitute.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_substitute.html

```
<Location />
    AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
    Substitute s/www.domainname1.tld/www.domainname2.tld/ni
</Location>
```

credit: http://corpocrat.com/2008/09/19/install-apache-mod_substitute/

Answer (score 0):

Altering file contents is outside the scope of a `.htaccess` file, or Apache in general.

If a link points to a domain, that domain is going to be called. You can add a redirect on that domain ([here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418283/joomla-move-whole-site-to-different-domain-name) an example how), but you can't prevent the request from ending up at the old domain.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar a case where we moved a lot of files to a new folder structure:

Old structure:

```
/css/
/images/
/js
/*.html
```

New structure:

```
/common/css/
/common/images/
/common/js
/<various_html_folders/*.html
```

The problem was that my html files referenced css, js and images by relative paths, and with the new structure I would have to update thousands of these references.

So I came across the mod_rewrite in Apache which rewrites the response body before it is sent to the client. I added the following 4 lines to my .htaccess file in order to change all `href="css/` to `href="/common/css/"`:

```
AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
Substitute 's|href="css/|="/common/css/|i'
Substitute 's|href="js/|="/common/js/|i'
Substitute 's|href="images/|="/common/images/|i'
```

And voila! css, javascripts and images work as before without updating any of my html files.

Disclaimer: I have not yet research the performance impact of doing this. Keep in mind that a regular expression is executed on the entire response body for every `Substitute` line you add.